# With Git, how can I get my most recent check-in?

Tags: git, terminal

I performed a

```
git log
```

and then I checked out a version about 10 versions back to poke around via...

```
git checkout akdsgh98afguafd7adfg34g4
```

Now, I want to go back to my most recent checkin. However, when I do a

```
git log
```

It only shows me versions older than the one I recently checked out. How do I get back to my most recent version?

Comment: @NightShadeQueen, definitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git checkout master
```

Replace `master` with another branch name if you are not on the master branch. (Check which branch you are on with `git branch`)

You can also do

```
git checkout -
```

which will take you to the latest commit on the branch you are on.

Comment: What if you can't remember what branch you were on (or you thought you were on `master`, but then you second-guess yourself thinking you might've accidentally been on some tmp branch like `throwaway`) Is there a history (even if only of length 1) of this kept somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the other branch you were on before you started to poke around:

```
git checkout master
```

Comment: How can you checkout an older folder for a certain commit. For example, I don't want the entire commit, I just want /myDir/blah for a certain commit.

Comment: @chrisP Please ask a new question as a new question (preferably after searching), not as a follow-up to your current question.